# C++ Container with Fastest "Exists" Seeking (Vector/Array/etc)

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector

I'm not sure the best C++ data container to use here.... I'm building an application that's very sensitive to latency (so I need the absolute fastest implementation).

I need to store about 300,000 strings one-time (only one write), then frequent checks if an element exists in that data store (many reads).  I never need to do anything else with this data set except check if a value exists within it, and I'll need to check this hundreds of times per second.  If it matters, the MAJORITY of lookups will result in the key NOT being found.

I've considered using a vector or array, but they all seem to simply scan through the entire list and inspect value one-to-one... which would work... but since we're indexing strings, isn't there any data container that builds some kind of tree index for the values, so when searching for the value "apple", it'll first look at keys beginning with "a", then the next character "p", and when it doesn't find any "ap..." it immediately returns not found.  To me this seems like it'd be faster than searching the entire massive set each time.  I'm really hoping a native container has this kind of functionality.

This project does have Boost compiled in, if that helps.

Thanks so much!

Comment: `std::set` and `std::map` build a red-black tree. `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` are hash tables.

Comment: @MichałGóral C++ does not specify the specific type of tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Boost, the answer is clearly `boost::unordered_set`.

It's also available as part of the standard in C++11 as `std::unordered_set` in `<unordered_set>`.

They're both built on a hash table, so it's O(1) for the lookup itself once the hash is computed.

Comment: And forgive my ignorance, but it's save to assume the `unordered_set` hash table is faster than the red-black tree from a normal `set` for simple "if exists" lookups?

Comment: It's average O(1) lookup and linear in worst case while std::set is always O(log(N))

Comment: Perfect, since I don't believe there's better than O(1) for what I'm trying to do, `unordered_set` it is.  Thank you!

Comment: @Harry, it's not *guaranteed* to be faster, but it's *likely* to be faster for large datasets. If it's that important you should really benchmark it for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

That tree container is called [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

[Here](https://github.com/ithlony/Boost.Trie) you can find Boost.Trie, I haven't used it, so I don't know if it is completed.

Comment: That sounds interesting, and is what I was describing, but might be a bit too much overhead for the speed requirements I have.

Comment: Trie should presumably perform better especially if there are many misses.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you can keep the data in memory than the best container for that purpose would be unordered_set. It has O( 1 ) access time if you need to check if some key exist within the set. Boost offers pretty good implementation which you can find here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/unordered.html.

If you can't keep the data in memory because it's too big you can use different trick. You can calculate some small hash of each string ( you can find different hash functions ) so it works like conversion from string -> int basically. Then whenever you need to test if string exists in your database you can just convert it to int ( using the same hash function ) and check in hash table if it exists. You can associate the hash value with the offset of a string in file if you need to retrieve the data but in your case you can think of keeping the hash values only if you need to save space.

PS. unordered_set uses hash function too it's just hidden.